# 100k stars achievement in Sky Force 2014

Tags: android, sky-force-2014

I collected over 100k stars [Sky Force 2014](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=pl.idreams.skyforcehd&hl=en), but didn't get the 100k stars achievement. Any idea why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: i'm assumng the problem here is  they might of released an update with those achievements AFTER you gained a majority of your stars

Comment: @Sickest I got the stars after the achievement got released.

Comment: Chalk it up to a bug in the game, maybe email the devs?